# Localnotification not Showing on android phone

Tags: codenameone

I have wrote the code as it is written in the developer guide.
But I'm not receiving any notification on simulator as well as on android.
Double smtng=10;
Double smtng1=10;

```
if(smtng1==smtng) {
LocalNotification ln = new 
 LocalNotification();
   ln.setId("sola");
  ln.setAlertBody(".....');


ln.setAlertTitle("local");

Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(ln, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100000, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
```

}

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48071506/756809

Comment: No! I put the app on background but I didn't get any notification. I have tried it so many times on android and simulator.

Comment: You need to try this on the device, this isn't a feature of the simulator. Try adding `setAlertTitle` as well just to be sure. Also which Android OS are you using? When you run this with a cable connected and logcat do you see something printed to the device log?